# Print format unicode list

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a list of unicode objects in Python 2.7. I want to format a print statement that will print this list.

```
unicode_list = [u'something', u'\u25ba']
print u'Unicode list %s' % unicode_list
```

The above code prints `Unicode list [u'something', u'\u25ba']`.

But

```
print unicode_list[1]
```

prints `►` as expected.

How can I format string properly to print a unicode list? Like so: `Unicode list ['something', '►']`

Comment: I don't think that my question is a duplicate. How does this solve my problem?

Comment: Yeah, ok, I may have misunderstood the question. What's the output you want to get?

Comment: I agree, this question is not a duplicate.  On a more helpful note, it looks like you're running into the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`. Try `print '[%s]' % u', '.join(unicode_list)`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This works for me, you can add that as an answer.

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3, and your "problem" will magically disappear.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that '%s' in your string formatting expects a string and you give it a list. It will collapse the entire list into a single string before plugging that in.

I have found it's easier to make strings from lists by using concatenation:

```
print "Unicode list ['%s']" % u"', '".join(unicode_list)
```

Comment: You'll need the u in there. This is a unicode list.

Comment: I don't think you need the u before the join string, since it is already in the list items. Patrick Haugh provided a comment that kind of addresses the brackets and quotes. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: No, don't mix unicode and string. The prefix and the join string should also be unicode strings.